# Unable to parse Json object to json array

Tags: java, json, gson

I have request with sample json as

```
{data=[{id=56908, name=ishant, address=}]}
```

and corresponding pojo to this is as below:

```
class Student{
    long id;
    String name;
    List<Address> addss;
}
```

Address is not a JSON Array and can not be deserialized.

Is there any way I can prevent my address list to get deserialized but allow it to get serialized?

Comment: The POJO doesn't match the "json" (that is not valid BTW). If you want fine tuning over the de/serialization use some custom "converter" see [the doc](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization)

Comment: WHat is the issue with the json and POJO matching. Please help .

Comment: The POJO should be some class that has a list of Student named data

Comment: That is fine In the end I have another class as StudentList which memebr vairbale as LIst<Student>  but i ma getting an error with address .....In the json i ma getting addrss as object but during desrialisation it is ecpecting an list of address . How could i resolve that.

Comment: It is a big mystery how a parser would find anything but an error for `address`.

Comment: Could you include an example of the actual json please